# JS Highlighting Of Text Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, highlighting

Using a small plugin to highlight text strings from an input field within a form.

[JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

I have modified the code slightly to allow the user to add multiple strimgs into the input field by splitting them with a comma which will highlight multiple keywords.

This works great in this instance: stack,overflow,js

However if I was to type in stack,overflow,js, (note the , after the last string) it hangs the browser and becomes unresponsive.

The code I am using is:

```
$(function() { 
    if ( $("input#searchterm").val().length > 0 ) {
        $("input#searchterm").addClass('marked-purple');
        var arrayOfKeyWords= $("input#searchterm").val().split(',');
        for (var i=0;i<arrayOfKeyWords.length;i++) {
            $('.message p.messagecontent').highlight(arrayOfKeyWords[i]);
        }
    }           
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to ignore the last comma if the user has added it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do an empty value check before calling `highlight()`, like this:

```
if ($("#searchterm").val().length > 0) {
    $("#searchterm").addClass('marked-purple');
    var arrayOfKeyWords = $("#searchterm").val().split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfKeyWords.length; i++) {
        if (arrayOfKeyWords[i] !== "") { // ensure there is a value to highlight
            $('.message p.messagecontent').highlight(arrayOfKeyWords[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could strip the trailing commas if there are any.

```
if ($("#searchterm").val().length > 0) {
    $("#searchterm").addClass('marked-purple');
    var arrayOfKeyWords = $("#searchterm").val().replace(/,+$/, '').split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfKeyWords.length; i++) {
        $('.message p.messagecontent').highlight(arrayOfKeyWords[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you can remove last comma of a string:

```
var str = "stack,overflow,js,"; 
if(str.charAt( str.length-1 ) == ",") {
  str = str.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: The question is how to ignore the last comma!